# Python Int object not callable

Tags: python, object, int

Please help! I don't understand the error here. Why do I get an error saying: "'int' object is not callable" when I type a number other than 0, 1 or 2? Instead, it's suppose to print "You have entered an incorrect number, please try again" and go back to asking the question.

Second Question: Also how can I change the code in a way that even if I type letter characters, it won't give me the Value Error and continue re-asking the question? Thank you!

```
def player_action():        
    player_action = int(input("Enter 0 to stay, 1 to go Up, or 2 to go Down: "))

    if player_action == 0:
        print ("Thank You, you chose to stay")


    if player_action == 1:
        print ("Thank You, you chose to go up")

    if player_action == 2:
        print ("Thank You, you chose to go down")

    else:
        print ("You have entered an incorrect number, please try again")
        player_action()

player_action()
```

Comment: Your variable name shadows the function name. You try to call the function `player_action()`but are actually calling the variable `player_action`, which is an int. Don't use the same name for the function and the variable!

Comment: Also, there is no reason to make this function recursive. Just put a `while` loop until you get a valid input and then do something with that input.

Comment: oh okay thank you!

Comment: sorry could you show me how I can rewrite this using while function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the variable name as @Pedro Lobito suggest, use a `while` loop as @Craig suggested, and you can also include the `try...except` statement, but **not** the way @polarisfox64 done it as he had placed it in the wrong location.

Here's the complete version for your reference:

```
def player_action():    
    while True:   
        try:
            user_input = int(input("Enter 0 to stay, 1 to go Up, or 2 to go Down: "))
        except ValueError:
            print('not a number')
            continue

        if user_input == 0:
            print ("Thank You, you chose to stay")          

        if user_input == 1:
            print ("Thank You, you chose to go up")

        if user_input == 2:
            print ("Thank You, you chose to go down")

        else:
            print ("You have entered an incorrect number, please try again")
            continue
        break

player_action()
```

Answer (score 1):

The first answer to your question has been answered by Pedro, but as for the second answer, a try except statement should solve this:

EDIT: Yeah sorry, I messed it up a little... There are better answers but I thought I should take the time to fix this

```
def player_action():
    try:
        player_action_input = int(input("Enter 0 to stay, 1 to go Up, or 2 to go Down: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Non valid value") # or somehting akin
        player_action()
    if player_action_input == 0:
        print ("Thank You, you chose to stay")
    elif player_action_input == 1:
        print ("Thank You, you chose to go up")
    elif player_action_input == 2:
        print ("Thank You, you chose to go down")
    else:
        print ("You have entered an incorrect number, please try again")
            player_action()

player_action()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the variable name `player_action` to a diff name of the function, i.e.:

```
def player_action():
    user_input = int(input("Enter 0 to stay, 1 to go Up, or 2 to go Down: "))
    if user_input == 0:
        print ("Thank You, you chose to stay")
    elif user_input == 1:
        print ("Thank You, you chose to go up")
    elif user_input == 2:
        print ("Thank You, you chose to go down")
    else:
        print ("You have entered an incorrect number, please try again")
        player_action()

player_action()
```